# R Function shinyApp will not run

Tags: r, shiny

I absolutely cannot figure out why my shiny app will not run. I'm fairly new to shiny I will mention. I'm running the following code locally, but when I run it, it never completes, just sits there. Any help is GREATLY appreciated. Code is below:

```
   ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Hello World!"),
    
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
            sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                        label = "Number of bins:",
                        min = 5,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
            
        ),
        
        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(
            
            # Output: Histogram ----
            plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
            
        )
    )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Histogram of the Old Faithful Geyser Data ----
    # with requested number of bins
    # This expression that generates a histogram is wrapped in a call
    # to renderPlot to indicate that:
    #
    # 1. It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
    #    re-executed when inputs (input$bins) change
    # 2. Its output type is a plot
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        
        x    <- faithful$waiting
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "orange",
             xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
             main = "Histogram of waiting times")
        
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result: [image]
It never completes, just sits there.

Comment: it runs just fine for me. It should be named `app.R`. Try typing this in the console? `runApp('C:/Full/Path/to/App/app.R')`

Comment: Try running code in New Shiny Web App (File -> New File -> Shiny Web App...)

Comment: Baroque, the console still just hangs. Isn't completing. Ran the following: "runApp('C:/Users/M0185JN/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/App-1/FinancialPlanning/app.R')"

Comment: sm0k313 I also created a new web app and it still failed to complete. I will mention that I am on a work computer. Would a firewall hold this up? I wouldn't think that it would since I'm running it locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the answer to this. It was a permission thing with my company. If anyone runs into this issue in the future, be sure to evaluate your level of internet permissions.